# Trying to get an existing database, Room Android

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-assets

Good afternoon. I make an existing database in the application. I want to address her through the Room, but I get an error `IllegalArgumentException: Cannot provide null context for the database.`.
My code looks like this:

```
    @Database(entities = {Series.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
    public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "base.db";

    public abstract CymbalDao cymbalDao();

    public static AppDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                            AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Database location:

```
..\src\main\assets\base.db
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, and maybe hear some tips, Thank you!

Called by Fragment:

```
public class CymbalsFragment extends Fragment {

    List<CymbalSeries> cymbalSeries = new ArrayList<>();
    CymbalsAdapter cymbalsAdapter;

    final AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getContext());
    final CymbalDao cymbalDao = db.cymbalDao();
```

Logcat:

```
08-15 15:46:23.247 31769-31769/ru.alexsuvorov.paistewiki W/System.err: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot provide null context for the 
database.
08-15 15:46:23.248 31769-31769/ru.alexsuvorov.paistewiki W/System.err:     at     android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:600)
    at ru.alexsuvorov.paistewiki.db.AppDatabase.getDatabase(AppDatabase.java:25)
    at ru.alexsuvorov.paistewiki.fragments.CymbalsFragment.<init>(CymbalsFragment.java:29)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at ru.alexsuvorov.paistewiki.StartDrawer.onNavigationItemSelected(StartDrawer.java:70)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:154)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
    at 
 android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
```

Comment: is it an activity , can you post more code ?

Comment: @kdblue I'm edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getContext());
```

this line is retuning the context null. Context is yet not attached to the fragment. This can happen if you call getContext() in the constructor of fragment. Call getContext() in onCreateView or onViewCreated().

Sample code

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            Context context = getContext();
            final AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly! Can you tell me about using exiting database? I doing correctly?